# "Proof" of a combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I request help on the following "proof":

$$\binom{n-1}{0}\cdot\binom{r}{1}+\binom{n-1}{1}\cdot\binom{r}{2}+...+\binom{n-1}{r-1}\cdot\binom{r}{r}=\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}.$$

My Attempt:

I wrote an MS Excel macro to check for many combinations.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim n, r, Sum, score As Integer, result As String

n = Range("A5").Value

r = Range("B5").Value

Range("C5").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Combin(n + r - 1, r - 1)

Sum = 0

For i = 0 To r - 1

    sum = sum + Application.WorksheetFunction.Combin(n - 1, i) * Application.WorksheetFunction.Combin(r, i + 1)

Next i

Range("D5").Value = Sum

End Sub
```

The cells C5 and D5 match for the examples I chose.

The equation just becomes ugly if I try to open it up. Maybe there is a way if I use induction. Could anyone provide a hint (some property of combinations that I can use here)?

Please advise.

Comment: Are you asking about a proof for the identity, or about your computational work to obtain evidence supporting the identity? For the former, it just seems to be (an instance of) the Vandermonde identity in a slight disguise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are familiar with the [Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$$\binom x0\binom yk+\binom x1\binom y{k-1}+\cdots+\binom xk\binom y0=\binom{x+y}k.$$
Setting $\ x=n-1,\ y=r,\ k=r-1\ $ we get
$$\binom{n-1}0\binom r{r-1}+\binom{n-1}1\binom r{r-2}+\cdots+\binom{n-1}{r-1}\binom r0=\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$$
which is the same as the identity you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 2):

Induction over r is the way to go. The key step is to use ${r+1 \choose k+1} = {r \choose k} + {r \choose k+1}$ just before you use your induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative proof

Suppose there are $n-1$ boys and $r$ girls.

Then there are $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ possibilities to select $r-1$ of them.

If you pick $i$ boys - wich can be done on $\binom{n-1}i$ ways - then you are bound to pick $r-1-i$ girls - wich can be done on $\binom{r}{r-1-i}=\binom{r}{i+1}$ ways.

That leads to the equality:$$\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}\binom{n-1}{i}\binom{r}{i+1}=\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$$

Comment: Thanks for explaining with a simple example :)

Comment: You are very welcome.